# Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver doesn't fully restore by NuGet

Tags: selenium, nuget, nuget-package

In my project I use `Selenium.WebDriver` and 
when try to execute command

```
\.NuGet install Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver.2.44.0.0
```

I expect to see `IEDriverServer.exe` file, but package has been downloaded not fully.
Command `\.NuGet restore` gaved  the same result.

There are:

- Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver.2.44.0.0

  - content

    - README-IEDriver.txt(contains "This is dummy text")
  - tools

    - Int.ps1
    - Install.ps1
    - Uninstall.ps1
  - Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver.2.44.0.0.nupkg

As you see there is no file `IEDriverServer.exe` file

**Here is my Environment Information:**
Size of folder: *14.6 Kb*

OS: *Windows Server 2008 R2*

NuGet: *2.8.2*

Parameters of powershell running: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process`

Answer (score 0):

NuGet.exe will not run PowerShell scripts. PowerShell scripts are only run when the NuGet package is installed from within Visual Studio.

NuGet.exe install and NuGet.exe restore will both download the NuGet package's .nupkg file and extract it.

The Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver NuGet package uses a PowerShell script to download the executable to the content directory. Since it is not in the .nupkg file then NuGet.exe on the command line will not download it.